# How can I remove the file path when using Glob()?

Tags: php, glob

I just want to display the name of my images, without the path (`../uploadedImages/`)

```
<?php $images = glob("../uploadedImages/[kK]*.{jpg,png,gif,bmp}",GLOB_BRACE);   
foreach($images as $image) {echo "$image<br>"} ?>
```

Comment: If you `chdir()`, you can omit the path from the result strings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
echo basename($image) . "<br>";
```

Comment: If you just need an array of files: `$files = array_map('basename', $files);`

Answer (score 0):

Although basename is good for a single file, if you need to cut the path for several files that glob gives as array, this way works great.

```
$contents = str_replace( __DIR__, '', glob( __DIR__ .'/*' ) );
```